# Picking Ticket with Bins

Tags: pdf, netsuite, freemarker, bin, bfo

I created a picking ticket with BINS on it using advanced pdf in NetSuite. The items are sorted by BINS. Items can have multiple bins. I noticed that when the BIN quantity is lower than the Order quantity then the BIN does not show on the print out. For example I need 100 for item A with 2 bins with available quantities. Let's say BIN1 has 150 and BIN2 has 50. The picking ticket will only show BIN1 even if both BINS have available quantities. Is there a way to show both BINS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Bin1 the preferred bin?

Comment: Nope, I don't have any preferred BIN.